# Android: append Query Parameter without a key in URI Builder

Tags: java, android, uri

I am using a web API for a service "https://somedomain.net/api/items.php?token=token&item" to retrieve a Json response.

In Android I am using a URI builder as:

```
    public static URL buildUrl(String token, String item) {
        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_TOKEN, token)
                .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_ITEM, item)
                .build();

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return url;
    }
```

As result for the URI Builder "https://somedomain.net/api/items.php?token=token&item=item"

I need to use the value "item" without a parameter key.

I tried using "null" didn't work "https://somedomain.net/api/items.php?token=token&=item"

I was looking in the internet for 3 days no luck for an answer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function to addQueryParam without value, so you may add some dummy value, "", for example, and then replace it with empty string (replace("=", "")).

But I recommend you to build query by himself and then append queryString with "query" function of Uri.Builder.

```
public static URL buildUrl(String token, String item) {
    String query = new StringBuilder()
            .append(PARAM_TOKEN).append("=").append(token).append("&")
            .append(PARAM_ITEM).toString();

    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
            .encodedQuery(query)
            .build();

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return url;
}
```

But it requires BASE_URL to has no any query params. If it has then you have to build new Uri from parts of the old one, but replace query with your own query builded from BASE_URL query and your additional params

Comment: change ```.query(query)``` to ```.encodeQuery(query)``` it works for me.